# contains throwing exception while comparing json object

Tags: karate

i am trying to compare json using contains, i am getting an error while comparing.

```
Feature:

Scenario:
Given def cat = 
"""
{
  name: 'Billie',
  kittens: [
    { id: 23, name: 'Bob' },
    { id: 42, name: 'Wild' },
    { id: 43, name: 'Wild', val: 'test', charging_model : {model: "test",overage : "NAN"}}
  ]
}
"""
Then match cat.kittens contains [{ id: 42, name: 'Wild' }, { id: 23, name: 'Bob' }]
Then match $cat.kittens contains { id: 43, name: '#string', charging_model : {overage : "NAN"} }
```

Exception:

```
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: path: $.kittens[*], actual: [{"id":23,"name":"Bob"},{"id":42,"name":"Wild"},{"id":43,"name":"Wild","val":"test","charging_model":{"model":"test","overage":"NAN"}}], expected: {id=43, name=#string, charging_model={overage=NAN}}, reason: actual value does not contain expected
    at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.matchNamed(StepDefs.java:540)
    at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.matchContains(StepDefs.java:532)
    at ✽.Then match $cat.kittens contains { id: 43, name: '#string', charging_model : {overage : "NAN"} }
```

If my json doesn't contain json object its working,

```
 {
          name: 'Billie',
          kittens: [
            { id: 23, name: 'Bob' },
            { id: 42, name: 'Wild' },
            { id: 43, name: 'Wild', val: 'test'}
          ]
        }
Then match $cat.kittens contains { id: 43, name: '#string' } //It is working
```

Kindly help me how can i compare json using contains which has json object inside json.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it. You are actually doing 3 levels of `contains` the first one is an array, the next 2 are JSON partial objects :)

If you do an exact match (full JSON objects) this will work as expected:

```
Then match cat.kittens contains { id: 43, name: '#string', val: 'test', charging_model: { model: 'test', overage : 'NAN' } }
```

If you don't want to specify all the fields, what you need to do is break down your JSON into named pieces like this:

```
* def testModel = { overage: 'NAN' } 
* def testKitten = { charging_model: '#(^testModel)' }
* match cat.kittens contains '#(^testKitten)'
```

This is explained in detail in the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#contains-short-cuts

EDIT: in 0.9.6 onwards `contains deep` can simplify this:

https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1287658286657855490